# Automatic way to find where variables are coming from in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Whenever I have to change something in our Ansible repository, I have to check all the places where a [variable could be set](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#where-to-set-variables) and that's very time consuming.

Is there something that would show me something like "the varialbe X being used in this template file is defined is all these places for host Y"?

Comment: No. It is not. It's up to you to keep track of [where the variables are coming from](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). In fact, asking this question indicates that something is wrong with the structure of the data.

Comment: thanks for your useful answer, much appreciated

Comment: Post your [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) problem, instead. There might be options on how to improve the structure of the data or how to efficiently debug issues.

Comment: Using an IDE with decent search functionalities should make this a breeze. Example for pycharm which I usually use for ansible development. Hitting `ctrl-shift-F`, selecting 'In project" and entering "my_variable_name:" (note the ending column) immediately gives me the list of files and the lines where that variable is set. The documentation site proposes a [list of IDEs and plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/community/other_tools_and_programs.html#popular-editors). Looking with grep is also a simple option: from your project root => `grep -Rn "my_variable_name:" *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar problem in our company. Very large inventory where it was hard to keep track where a variable is defined and what "wins" (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

I have written a simple tool to solve that: https://github.com/hille721/ansible-variables

But this only works for host context variables yet, thus not for playbook or role variables

Answer (score 2):

I think shell is your best friend for this use case :

```
grep -ERl "your_vars|{{ your_vars }}" /path/to/your/ansible/code
```

May do the trick.

Comment: This ignores variable precedence order, which is what is most time consuming to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Asked feature request:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/82204 - Identifying origin of variable: env var / -e / host file / group file